# How do sub shells work under the hood in Linux?

Tags: linux

My understanding is that sub shells fork a child process off of the parent process and that any commands in the parentheses are executed using execve.  The parent process waits for the child process to finish executing.  Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Of course not the sub shells fork a child process, but the parent shell does.

Comment: Please add a example and explain why it puzzles you. This makes it easier to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sub shell may fork to create the subshell, and then for each external cmmand in `()`, fork again before calling execve.

If the commands in `()` are internal commands, then it would not need to fork and execve for those.